# Last Id Not Detected

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a trigger .Like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `villa` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_a`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_a` (`id`, `name`, `villa`) VALUES
(1, 'KAKUL', 'ASHOK NAGER');

--
-- Triggers `tbl_a`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `test` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl_a`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO tbl_b_bckup(a_id,name,villa) SELECT (id,name,villa) FROM tbl_a WHERE id = @id
//
DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_b_bckup`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_b_bckup` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `villa` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

If i replace @id with no its works but . i need last updated rows_id . How can i get it? 
I want that Before update any thing on tbl_a . A backup row will be create on tbl_b_backup . 
This query not even allow me to edit the tbl_a

Comment: Is it belongs to SQL Server??

Comment: id is auto increment how to possible to passing value to this column????

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbl_b_bckup(a_id,name,villa) SELECT (id,name,villa) FROM tbl_a WHERE id = @id`     I am not updating id pushing tbl_a.id to tbl_b_bckup.a_id

Comment: Have you looked at standard methods for replication?

Comment: i have got the error `INSERT INTO tbl_b_bckup(a_id,name,villa) SELECT id,name,villa  FROM tbl_a WHERE id = @id` BY REMOVING () FRM SELECT ... BUT ISSUE IS STILL I AM NOT ABLE TO GET THE @ID value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl_a`
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO tbl_b_bckup(a_id,name,villa)
VALUES (OLD.id,OLD.name,OLD.villa)
```

There is no need to select the row from tbl_a.  You already have it in a pseudo-row known by the alias `OLD`.

Answer (score 1):

Use OLD.id to get reference of old column value and NEW.id for new column value